# How to mention a function of functions in flowchart of an algorithm

Tags: algorithm, flowchart

I want to show a function in a flowchart which is itself a function of two other functions. How can I do that? Currently I have shown it as you see in figure. But I think it is not correct because it means that first sorting will be done and then two other functions (pareto... and crowding distance) which is not correct.

I want to show so that Sorting will be done by two functions: Pareto... and Crowding distance.

---

[image: Flowchart including function Sort which itself is a function of two other functions]

---

Answer (score 0):

Using a `Predefined Process` allows the inclusion of multiple `Processes` (functions) as if they were presented inline. In this case, `Sort Population` consists of the two functions in the `Predefined Process`.

---

[image: Example of Predefined Process]

---

Comment: Many thanks Rick. how did you created the chart? It is not easy to create charts in keynote. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @H.Radmard - I used LibreDraw, part of LibreOffice 6.2.